# How to live uploading video on a folder while filming at the same time this video in c# for ASP.NET Wep Api?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, video, video-streaming

is there a way to live upload a video in a folder while im filming it?

I mean by that that while im recording a video i want at the same time uploading it on a folder:if i cut the record intentionnaly or unintentionnaly there will be a copy in the folder as it's live uploading.

Comment: If there is a way, ASP .NET web api would not be appropriate. You might ask this question someplace streamers hang out.

Comment: @crowcoder thanks for the answer.Does it means it impossible in .net? cause i don't want to stream i just want to film and record on folder at the same time.which solution i have?

Comment: That is not something I am familiar with so I can't help you. You might find a library that does it. I know that [Wowza](https://www.wowza.com/) has SDKs for live streaming but as far as I know there is no c# version. Since c# can do TCP I'm sure you could make it happen, whether it is practical or not is another matter.

Comment: @crowcoder ok i will check on it. but can we really say it's streaming as i just want to save video in the same time im recording it. i don't want to stream the video to other people or stuff

Answer (score 0):

you want to essentially ensure that if there is an issue, the video is still saved. This solution is not c# based, but more based on web streaming protocols.

Many live streaming services offer the capability to save a video after a live stream is completed.  [api.video](https://api.video) allows you to live stream (to no one, if you desire), and upon completion, a copy of your video is available (nearly instantly) for playback on the server.